# Excel - Two columns (A)Company (B)Team Members. Need to identify which Companies do not have Team Members a,c and c

Tags: excel, excel-formula

this is making my brain melt.

This is an analogue of what I'm trying to achieve.

I have an extract of data from a database in Excel. Column A is Company. Column B is Team Members.

Is is structured like this, for example, Company a is shown four times because it has four team members, members a,c,f and d.

Goal: I want to identify all companies that do not contain team members a,b and c. Ideally this will use a formula rather than VBA.

Really hoping someone wouldn't mind spending the time to help.

Example data below, I can't figure out how to paste this as a table, so I've pasted the column values as two separate strings.

```
+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B |
+----------+----------+
| a        | a        |
| a        | c        |
| a        | f        |
| a        | d        |
| b        | g        |
| b        | e        |
| b        | a        |
| b        | c        |
| c        | r        |
| c        | a        |
| c        | b        |
| c        | d        |
| c        | e        |
| c        | h        |
| c        | t        |
| d        | e        |
| d        | f        |
| d        | d        |
| d        | s        |
| d        | w        |
| d        | q        |
| e        | f        |
| e        | a        |
| e        | b        |
| e        | r        |
| e        | w        |
| f        | u        |
| f        | k        |
| f        | n        |
| f        | p        |
| f        | l        |
| g        | h        |
| g        | a        |
| g        | c        |
| g        | e        |
| g        | r        |
| g        | g        |
| h        | v        |
| h        | c        |
| h        | d        |
| h        | a        |
| h        | e        |
| h        | r        |
| h        | t        |
| h        | g        |
| i        | n        |
| i        | g        |
| i        | e        |
| i        | y        |
| i        | n        |
| j        | r        |
| j        | w        |
| j        | j        |
| j        | u        |
| k        | y        |
| k        | h        |
| k        | k        |
| k        | u        |
| k        | b        |
| l        | g        |
| l        | j        |
| l        | l        |
| l        | u        |
+----------+----------+
```

Many thanks,

Matt.

Comment: how do you want to show the "companies that do not contain team members a,b and c"???

Answer (score 0):

A simple `IF` formula in `Column C`,

`=IF(AND(B1<>"a",B1<>"b",B1<>"c"),A1,"")`

and drag it throughout the range. This would show all companies that do not have team members a,b and c. This might contain duplicate company names, which you may have to remove it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Copy this formula into the C column for every row containing Company and Team data.

```
=IF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW())<>INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1),IF(SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B" & ROW() & ":B" &   ROW() + COUNTIF($A:$A, INDIRECT("A"&ROW())) - 1), {"a","b","c"})) > 0, "", CONCATENATE("Company ",  INDIRECT("A"&ROW()), " does not contain Team Members a, b, or c")), "")
```

Here is a breakdown of what this formula is doing.

First off lets understand the usage of `INDIRECT`. This is building a reference to the correct cells based on the hardcoded "A" or "B" for the column and then finding the current row number by using `ROW()`. This allows you to place the formula anywhere in the row without worrying about having to redo your column references.

So, for example, if evaluating for row 6 the formula spelled out is this:

1. `IF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW())<>INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)`

   - If A6 does not equal A5 then continue, else show blank.

     - (This is how we know if we are evaluating a new company)
2. `COUNTIF($A:$A, INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))`

   - Count the number of cells in column A that are equal to A6.
3. `(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B" & ROW() & ":B" &   ROW() + ... - 1), {"a","b","c"})`

   - Count the number of times "a", "b", or "c" occurs in the range A6 through A9.
4. `IF(SUM( ... ) > 0, "", ...`

   - If the sum of the above count is greater than zero then show blank, else show our success message.
5. `CONCATENATE("Company ",  INDIRECT("A"&ROW()), " does not contain Teams a, b, or c")`

   - Build our success message using `INDIRECT` to get a reference to the company name.

The output looks like this.

[image]

That's it!

Comment: Ah, thanks. I misunderstood the question to mean 'or' instead of 'and' for the team members. I did not know that `INDIRECT` is to be avoided. I'd be curious to learn more about that.

Comment: After re-reading the post it is not very detailed, to me the `do not contain team members a,b and c` means that all three must be in the company for it to not count, I may be wrong.  Look up volatile functions.  volatile functions recalc every time excel reclalcs.  Non volatile functions only recalc when the underlying data changes.  It force excel to do a lot of calculations that are not needed.  Volatile functions will recalc even if the calculation is called by a different workbook.

Comment: Your formula without INDIRECT. PUt in C2 and copy/drag down: `=IF(A2<>A1,IF(SUM(COUNTIF($B2:INDEX(B:B,ROW() + COUNTIF($A:$A, A2) - 1), {"a","b","c"})) <>0, "", CONCATENATE("Company ", A2, " does not contain Team Members a, b, or c")), "")`

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an array formula, This will do AND, all three must be present to ignore:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$64,MATCH(1,(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$64,$A$2:$A$64,$B$2:$B$64,"a")*COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$64,$A$2:$A$64,$B$2:$B$64,"b")*COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$64,$A$2:$A$64,$B$2:$B$64,"c")=0)*(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$64)=0),0)),"")
```

Put it in E2, Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to confirm it an array formula. If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then drag/copy down.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

IF you want OR,IF any are present ignore:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$64,MATCH(1,(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$64,$A$2:$A$64,$B$2:$B$64,"a")+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$64,$A$2:$A$64,$B$2:$B$64,"b")+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$64,$A$2:$A$64,$B$2:$B$64,"c")=0)*(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$64)=0),0)),"")
```

Put it in E2, Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to confirm it an array formula. If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]